# socket.io emitted from one id

Tags: node.js, sockets

I did code by nodejs and angular4 with socket.io
I have been used 2 different browsers and I have checked connection and socket.io has gave 2 different socket.id but when emit the 2 browsers emitted from 1 id !

code in app.js

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){app.set('socket', socket);console.log('a user connected to :'+socket.id);socket.on('disconnect', function(){console.log('user disconnected');});});
```

code emit

```
        let socket     = req.app.get('socket');
        console.log('emit from :' +socket.id )
        socket.emit('chatroom-'+chat.room, chat);
```

code listen in client side

```
        this.socket.on('chatroom-'+this.roomData._id, (data)=>{
          console.log('socket push',data);             
        })
```

all my code

initialize socketio at app.js

```
//construct
const express       = require('express');
const app           = express();
const server        = require('http').createServer(app);
const io            = require('socket.io').listen(server);
const port          = 3000;

//initialize
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
///passport strategy
require('./config/passport');

//routes
const chat    = require('./routes/chat');
app.use('/chat',chat);


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    app.set('socket', socket);
    console.log('a user has connected as :'+socket.id);
    io.on('connection', function () {
        console.log('a user has disconnected ');
    });

});

//start server code
server.listen(port, ()=> {
    console.log('node serve has been started on port : '+port);
})
```

emit chat after add new message at chat.js route

```
///add new chat
router.post('/add', passport.authenticate('jwt',{session:false}), (req,res,next) => {
    //validation
    if(!req.user._id){ res.json({status:false, message:'something went wrong, please sign-in first and try again'}) }
    if(req.user._id != req.body.user){ res.json({status:false, message:'something went wrong, please sign-in first and try again'}) }
    if(!req.body.room){ res.json({status:false, message:'something went wrong, please refresh the page and try again'}) }
    if(!req.body.text){ res.json({status:false, message:'you have to fill a chat message to add it'}) }
    next();
}, (req, res) => {
    //create new one 
    let chatData = new Chat(req.body);

    //do create
    Chat.create(chatData, (err, chat)=>{
        //error 
        if(err){ res.josn({status:false, message:err.message})}
        else{
            //replace user id to user data
            chat.user = req.user;
            //define socketio
            let socket     = req.app.get('socket');
            //emit new message
            socket.broadcast.emit('chatroom-'+chat.room, chat);
            //return respone
            res.json({status:true, message:'the message has been sent', chat:chat})
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Doing `app.set('socket', socket)` is like putting `socket` into a global and assumes you only have one user ever connected to your server at a time and a second user will overwrite the first and so on.  This is clearly a wrong design.  You don't seem to know what the actual problem is that you're trying to solve so we can't really help further except to tell you where this code is flawed.

Comment: I can't access io into node.js routes so I used this way ( app.set('socket','socket')

Comment: Well, that's just wrong code.  It does not allow your server to ever work properly with more than one user.  You'd have to describe in greater detail what you're trying to do and show more code before people would know what better solution to suggest.

Comment: all I want to do a simple chat room , I initialize socket.io in app.js and emit new chat in chat router , I faced issue in chat route that can't access io.broadcast to avoid send notification to the sender cause that I used app.set('socket','socket')

Comment: Since we can't see the organization of your code into separate modules, we can't really advise on how to properly share `io` from one module to another.  It's likely you should be exporting it from one module and importing it into another.  If you show us how all your code is organized, we could probably make a suggestion in minutes.  Also, why are you doing `app.set(socket)`, when it appears that what you want access to is `io`, not `socket`.

Comment: I added full code that code work fine except one user if send message the other user received but if the other user send the both of them received

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to broadcast to a room from your route, you can change this:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    app.set('socket', socket);
    console.log('a user has connected as :'+socket.id);
    io.on('connection', function () {
        console.log('a user has disconnected ');
    });
});
```

to this:

```
// make io available via app object
app.set('io', io);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('a user has connected as :'+socket.id);
    io.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('a user has disconnected ');
    });
});
```

And, change this:

```
        let socket     = req.app.get('socket');
        //emit new message
        socket.broadcast.emit('chatroom-'+chat.room, chat);
```

to this:

```
        let io  = req.app.get('io');
        //emit new message
        io.emit('chatroom-'+chat.room, chat);
```

This will consistently send the chat to all users in the room.

---

If you want to send only to the other users in the room, not to the user who originated the message, then it will be easier if you send the message over socket.io, not via a form post.  Then, you can just use:

```
 socket.broadcast.emit('chatroom-'+chat.room, chat);
```

where `socket` is the socket that you received the message on over socket.io which you will have nice and handy.

Comment: that gave me error in server  side 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined'

Comment: @MahmoudNiypoo - I fixed a typo.  I meant for it to be `io.emit(...)`.

Comment: okey it's work fine , but i can't able to access on broadcast to avoid the sender ! how can I do it

Comment: @MahmoudNiypoo - The last part of my message explains one method.  Otherwise, you will have to introduce a session object and store the socket for each user in the session object so when your route is hit, you can get the socket object for that user from the session object.

Comment: the only way I can do this by store socket into the session ! right ?

Comment: @MahmoudNiypoo - Why don't you just send the chat message via socket.io intead of via form post?  Then, it's trivial.

Comment: I thought about that but , I want to know what way is right

Comment: @MahmoudNiypoo - Well most people send chat messages over socket.io.  Once you have the socket.io connection established, it's more efficient and simpler to just use it for sending messages.  You can design it with a session if you want too.  There is no "right" way.  I tend to choose the simple and efficient way unless I'm forced (for other reasons) to do something more complicated.